# How do I display directories in colour on remote systems over ssh via Terminal?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, colors, cluster

When I do `ls` in `Terminal.app`, I see that directories on my local system are in colour. However, when I connect to a remote cluster via `ssh`,  `ls` output is no longer coloured. Is there a way to have `ls` show directories in colour on remote systems I connect to with `ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

### `man ls` documentation points to the `-G' flag:

```
-G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining
         CLICOLOR in the environment.  (See below.)
```

Also, it goes on to say that if the environment variable `CLICOLOR` is set, displaying listings in colour will be an `ls` default.

In `/bin/sh` style shells, adding:

`CLICOLOR=''; export CLICOLOR`

In `csh` style shells, add instead:

`setenv CLICOLOR`

to the appropriate login script file on the remote systems will turn on colour.  Should the other systems not be Macs, consult their man pages on `ls` to see how colour might be enabled.

Comment: Thanks Nevin for your reply. Since I am  not familiar with linux things, I just wanna make sure. I will open "sh" with text editor and paste {CLICOLOR=''; export CLICOLOR} inside sh?

Comment: When you open a terminal window, a program that passes data to and from the system is launched.  This is called a shell.  There are several shells.  Some shells use the 'setenv VARIABLE' syntax, while others use the VARIABLE="";export VARIABLE to set global environment variables for the shell's session.  As well, each shell has their own startup scripts that they load when initialized.  So, before I can advise you what to do, I have to know what shell you're using.  If you open a new Terminal window, and type  "tty ; ps" it will display the shell's process info.  Paste the output here, pls.

Comment: Thanks again Nevin.Here is the output: 1411 ttys000    0:00.01 -bash

 1506 ttys001    0:00.01 -bash

Comment: Ok, your shell is /bin/bash which uses the export syntax, and loads .bashrc on startup.

Comment: enter this line into a terminal window:

echo 'CLICOLOR= ;export CLICOLOR' >> .bashrc

Then open a new window.  Your `ls` should then be colorized.

Comment: Nothing changed.ls still does not show directories in colour on remote systems I connect to with ssh.